# How to get button value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Unable to get the button value in jquery.

```
<head>
    <script        
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <p> This is para </p>
    <button> Hide </button>
    <script>
            function handle(){
                    value = $("button").attr("value");
                    alert(value);
            }

            $(function(){
                    $("button").click(handle);
            });
    </script>
```

What is the error on the above code. I need to handle the event triggered by the button, instead of "this". I already saw how to solve it using "this". So without "this", how to handle event

Comment: The `button` has no `value` attribute...

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery `.text()` method with the `button` element to grab the text value contained within. (e.g. The text between the open `<button>` and close `</button>` tags.)

What you're attempting is not working because the `button` element has no `value` attribute to retrieve.

**Get Text Example:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> This is para </p>

<button> Hide </button>

<script>
    function handle() {
        var buttonText = $("button").text();

        // Whatever you need to do with the text.
        alert(buttonText);
    }

    $(function(){
         $("button").click(handle);
    });
</script>
```

[**Working code pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKzvkG)

Conversely, you can also *set* the `button`'s text value using the same method by passing the desired value to it.

**Set Text Example:**

```
...
    $("button").text("My New Text");
...
```

**Documentation:** [jQuery `.text()` Method](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the **Text** inside your button just use:

`value = $("button").text()` instead of `value = $("button").attr("value")`

Your button does not have the `value` attribute from which you can get the data.

So you should use `.text()` method instead of `.attr()`

```
<body>

  <p> This is para </p>
  <button> Hide </button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<script>
  function handle(){
    value = $("button").text();
    alert(value);
  }

  $(function(){
    $("button").click(handle);
  });
</script>

</body>
```

[Working example in JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qimaten/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

button element has no value attribute associated so you must try grabbing the text within the tag `<button></button>`

you can use jquery's text() method to grab the text as

```
<html>
<head><title>demo</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var x= $('#btn').text();
      console.log(x);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id='btn'>Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```